# How can I check by React Hook Form if password contains a number?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

How can I check by React Hook Form and Yup if password contains a numbers, capital letters and special signs? I tried something like this below, using validate function but it doesn't work correctly. I have an error 'Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined'.

```
const Register = ({ setRegisterView }) => {
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string()
      .required("It is required.")
      .email("Email is wrong"),
    password: Yup.string()
      .required("It is required.")
      .min(8, "Password need to has 8 signs.")
.validate((value) => {
        return (
          [/[a-z]/, /[A-Z]/, /[0-9]/, /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/].every((pattern) =>
            pattern.test(value)
          ) ||
          "Information"
        );
      }),
});

  const {
    register: validate,
    formState: { errors },
    handleSubmit,
  } = useForm({ mode: "onSubmit", resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema) });

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(registerProcess)}>
        <FieldType>Email</FieldType>
        <StyledInput
          name="email"
          type="email"
          error={errors.email}
          {...validate("email")}
        />
        {errors.email && <Error>{errors.email.message}</Error>}
        <FieldType>Password</FieldType>
        <StyledInput
          name="password"
          type="password"
          error={errors.password}
          {...validate("password")}
        />
        {errors.password && <Error>{errors.password.message}</Error>}
        <LoginButton type="submit">SIGN UP</LoginButton>
      </Form>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're using `validate` which expects a `Promise` as the return value -> [Docs](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedvalidatevalue-any-options-object-promiseany-validationerror). You should instead use `test` here.

```js
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().required("It is required.").email("Email is wrong"),
    password: Yup.string()
      .required("It is required.")
      .min(8, "Password need to has 8 signs.")
      .test("passwordRequirements", "Information", (value) =>
        [/[a-z]/, /[A-Z]/, /[0-9]/, /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/].every((pattern) =>
          pattern.test(value)
        )
      )
  });
```

[image: Edit React Hook Form - FieldsArray - Yup validation - Min Length (forked)]

Comment: Yes, thats it! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your inputs

```
<Input type="email" 
       error={errors.email}
       {...register("email")}
/>
```

And note that the builtin validation doesn't work with external validation, so required won't do anything here.

Comment: the problem is not the e-mail field, but the password field

Comment: @somenoobyquestions Thank you, I'm not entirely sure what to do with my answer since the question is already answered, I'm just gonna delete it.